# Problem streaning media from netbook using samba

Tags: networking, server, video, samba, streaming

I am trying to use my netbook as a media server. I have set up Samba on both my laptop and netbook identically. The laptop streams media fine to the netbook and an Android tablet.
The netbook and its shared files can be seen by the tablet and laptop but will not stream to them. I get the message "Could not determine type of stream".
The laptop is able to display jpg files from the netbook.
Samba .conf file is identical.
Ubuntu 14.04 on both netbook and laptop. Samba installed at the same time, therefore the same.
Any help would be appreciated.